# im a newbie learning python help me with this error where it says traceback name error every time

Tags: python, input, traceback

i am completely a newbie and learning python in vscode
i dont understand why im getting this message help me to fix it

```
ho = input('what is your name')
print(ho)
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sar/Desktop/python/csp1.py", line 1, in <module>
    ho = input('what is your name')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

expecting;

```
ho = input('what is your name')
print(ho)
```

output;

```
what is your name sar
sar
```

Comment: Do you input `f` when asked to input your name? Most likely you run your code with python2, when you should be using python3. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/4046632

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with the python version  for python 3.8

#for string input

ho = str(input('Enter your name:'))
print(ho)

#for number input

ho = str(input('Enter your name:'))
print(ho)